# Use {{this}} as argument for helper in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following helper function in Meteor:

```
sourceArray : function () {

        sources = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                if (!isInArray(images[i].source, sources)) {
                    sources.push(images[i].source);
                }
            }

        return sources; 
      }
```

I also have this helper function:

```
imageTitle : function (source) {
          var index = sources.indexOf(source);
          return images[index].title;
      }
```

In my HTML, I want to use the helpers like this, passing `{{this}}` as an argument:

```
<div class="row">
                {{#each sourceArray}}
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src={{this}}>
                    </a>
                    <!-- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT -->
                    {{imageTitle {{this}} }}

                </div>
                {{/each}}
        </div>
```

Upon doing so, I received the following error:

```
Errors prevented startup:

 While building the application:
 art.html:55: Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, or null
 ...                <h3>{{imageTitle {{this}} }}</h3>
 ...
 ^
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `{{ imageTitle this }}`

Comment: It does not make sense to pass `this` into a helper because its context is already `this`. If you call `this` inside your helper, you can see actual context data. Read more about data context in templates: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/

Answer (score 5):

I'm on mobile right now but I'll give you a huge tip. Inside of the `each` block, you don't need to pass `this` to the helper. You can just call `this` in the JS and it'll refer to the same thing that you are  currently trying to pass in.

Answer (score 1):

Any helpers used inside a helper block will automatically be able to reference `this`. See the below MeteorPad for an example:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/LMmMTSPi6BDtii4zb/ThisThing